# python file shared across several processes

Tags: python, concurrency, locking, fcntl

I have a python process that runs continuously and read every 1 minute a cfg file from disk.

`run.py`

```
while True:
 parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
 parser.read('config.ini')
 time.sleep(60)
```

The user can run a second process that modifies the `config.ini`

`edit.py`

```
  def set_param(self, section, param, new_value):
        parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
        parser.read('config.ini')
        current_cfg = parser[section][param] = new_value
        with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
            current_cfg.write(f)
```

Now this code should have 2 properties:

1) `run.py` should read the config file only if it is not being edited by `edit.py` In other words it should wait until the function `set_param` is fully executed.

2) subsequent calls to `edit.py` should not create conflict. A new call should be executed only if the file is not owned from a previous call.

I think I need something like a locking mechanism. I have been looking at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fcntl.html but I am not sure it is the right tool and I am struggling to understand how to use it.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sometimes, when you think you need locking, you might benefit from a different approach that doesn't require it. If you run a separate service that accepts write requests from `edit.py` (updating its in-memory config and persisting it to disk) and responds to `run.py` with the current configuration, you have a single point of access. If you have it queue all requests -- both read and update -- and apply them in sequence, you can make it process-safe. This way only one process will ever touch the file in any way, and update requests will be applied before all subsequent read requests.

Comment: thanks this seems a reasonably approach. I need to see if I can use it in my case. Can you point me at any relevant resources ?  (I am not writing a web app)

Comment: Sorry, I gave it a start, but it's more work than I can really put into it. I'd suggest looking into both [async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) if you'd like to go this route.